# Using Image module to create an Image Gallery and view them using lightbox

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

The new version of the [Image module](http://drupal.org/project/image) has some components, one of them being image_gallery.module which creates some views and taxonomy for you to use.

Now I want that when the user clicks on an image uploaded into a gallery, it is displayed using lightbox. This was easily done when creating a content-type and setting the view to lightbox.

Now the questions are:

1. Should I use image_gallery module?

   - If yes, how can I implement lightbox to it?
2. Should I use the other way (creating content type and creating views manually)?
3. Am I doing it completely wrong? :)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to tell if you're doing it right, because you didn't really describe all of your requirements. Personally, I would also consider a solution without Image module, but with CCK, Imagefield and Imagecache.

Comment: @marcvangend - Thanks, I'll try using CCK, Imagefield and Imagecache.

All I want is galleries with images that when the user clicks on them, they are displayed with lightbox.

Comment: I built something like that with CCK/Imagefield/Imagecache a while ago. Just create a content type "gallery" and add a multi-value imagefield for the photo's. The Lightbox2 module (http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2) works well together with those other modules.

Answer (score 1):

I have found Jeff Eaton's Views Gallery to be a great and simple image gallery solution, and it will display images in Lightbox right out of the box.  You need to have the lightbox2 module installed first though...

Here's the module:
http://drupal.org/project/views_gallery

And here's a very informative screencast:
http://www.lullabot.com/articles/photo-galleries-views-attach